# Showing and capture information in the same template

Tags: python, django, templates

I don't know how to do that, I need to open a template when I click a botton

```
<a href=" {% url contrareferencia credencial=post.credencial_consultainicial  fecha=post.fecha_atencion_18|date:"Ymd" %}"                             class="btn">Contrareferencia</a></td>
```

This will show the information of the member, but I need a part of the template to be editable, at the same time.

This is the view that I use to show the information..

view.py

```
def contrareferencia_Detalle_view(request, credencial, fecha):
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = especialidad(request.POST)
    print data
    if data.is_valid():
        data.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Alta Exitosa!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
else:
    date_for_search = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y%m%d').date()
    formulario = get_object_or_404(PaseEspecilidad, especialidad_credencial=credencial,fecha_solic_1=date_for_search)
return render(request, 'Contrareferencia.html', {'formulario': formulario,'data':data})
```

Comment: You need to also pass a form to your template for the data you want to edit. If this form is for the `PaseEspecilidad` model, then it needs to be a model form. If you're posting to the same view, your view will also need to check for `request.method == 'POST'`. This is pretty basic stuff...perhaps working through the Django tutorials will be of benefit.

Comment: My main problem is that I need to show some dropdrown with information from a Foreing key, so when I do what you told, It show me the information that is in the data base, instend of the dropdown.

Comment: As I said before, these are things that require basic working knowledge of Django concerning forms and views. No offense, but if you're just getting started with Django, I would *highly* recommend working through the tutorials.

Comment: This view is really messy. What is `especialidad`? Where is your form class? Where is your check for `if form.is_valid()` ?